# equivalent of "apply" in Octave / Matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a function in Octave / Matlab such as this (the real one is much, much more complicated)

```
function result = foo (x, y, z)
  result = x + y + z;
endfunction
```

The normal way to invoke the function is as follows:

```
foo (1, 2, 3);
```

but I'd like to apply it to arguments packaged in an array like this:

```
myStuff = [1, 2, 3];
apply (foo, myStuff);
```

or

```
foo (myStuff);
```

I haven't been able to find the syntax needed for such an invocation in the documentation or on Google.

Comment: Normally in Matlab one calls functions directly, hence there is no native apply function (Python 3 has removed apply for similar reasons). Why are you looking for this? Is your goal to use it to "vectorize" a function that is not vectorized in some way or that you do not have access to the source code of?

Comment: I have functions with dozens of arguments (not hand-written; codegenned from a DSL) and I want to write test code for them; it's convenient to package argument test sets in arrays rather than to generate dozens of ad-hoc names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible if you place your arguments in a cell array and use the [**comma-separated list**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) operator **`:`**.

For instance:

```
c = {x, y, z};
foo(c{:});
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo(x,y,z);
```

Best,

Comment: Very nice.  Broadcasting function parameters is something not many people know.  +1.